# bash variable indirection can't echo variable containing a function argument?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to echo a variable containing a function argument, like this:       `echo ${str1_$1_str2}`

The script is like this:

```
func_test () {
  eval str1_$1_str2=sucker
  echo ${str1_$1_str2}
}

func_test 1
```

When I execute the shell script, the error says:

```
${str1_$1_str2}: bad substitution
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indirect parameter expansion might help:

```
func_test(){
  declare str1_$1_str2="foobar"
  local x="str1_${1}_str2"
  echo "${!x}"
}
func_test 222
```

Output:

```
foobar
```